# Download a remote image and save it to a Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am writing a Django app which will fetch all images of particular URL and save them in the database.

But I am not getting on how to use ImageField in Django.

Settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PWD, "../downloads/")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "htp://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/downloads/'
```

models.py

```
class images_data(models.Model):
        image_id =models.IntegerField()
        source_id = models.IntegerField()
        image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True, blank=True)
        text_ind=models.NullBooleanField()
        prob=models.FloatField()
```

download_img.py

```
def spider(site):
        PWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__ ))
        #site="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pune"
        hdr= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        outfolder=os.path.join(PWD, "../downloads")
        #outfolder="/home/mayank/Desktop/dreamport/downloads"
        print "MAYANK:"+outfolder
        req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        soup =bs(page)
        tag_image=soup.findAll("img")
        count=1;
        for image in tag_image:
                print "Image: %(src)s" % image
                filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
                outpath = os.path.join(outfolder, filename)
                urlretrieve('http:'+image["src"], outpath)
                im = img(image_id=count,source_id=1,image=outpath,text_ind=None,prob=0)
                im.save()
                count=count+1
```

I am calling download_imgs.py inside one view like

```
        if form.is_valid():
                url = form.cleaned_data['url']
                spider(url)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField

Comment: Do you want to save the images as blobs in the db  or the image paths

Comment: @mossplix - Either way... But if i save images as path then I also want images on my server

Comment: @PauloBu - I read that document many times.But not getting on how to proceed

Comment: How are you fetching the images?

Comment: @rockingskier - By Urlreterive command

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) is always good place to start

```
class ModelWithImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images',
    )
```

**UPDATED**

So this script works.

- Loop over images to download
- Download image
- Save to temp file
- Apply to model
- Save model

.

```
import requests
import tempfile

from django.core import files

# List of images to download
image_urls = [
    'http://i.thegrindstone.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/how-to-get-awesome-back.jpg',
]

for image_url in image_urls:
    # Stream the image from the url
    response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)

    # Was the request OK?
    if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        # Nope, error handling, skip file etc etc etc
        continue
    
    # Get the filename from the url, used for saving later
    file_name = image_url.split('/')[-1]
    
    # Create a temporary file
    lf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

    # Read the streamed image in sections
    for block in response.iter_content(1024 * 8):
        
        # If no more file then stop
        if not block:
            break

        # Write image block to temporary file
        lf.write(block)

    # Create the model you want to save the image to
    image = Image()

    # Save the temporary image to the model#
    # This saves the model so be sure that it is valid
    image.image.save(file_name, files.File(lf))
```

Some reference links:

1. [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) - "HTTP for Humans", I prefer this to urllib2
2. [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) - Save temporay file and not to disk
3. Django filefield [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save)

Comment: I did this Even changed MEDIA_ROOT path accordingly.. Now what?

Comment: OK, so is the problem getting the image into the DB or accessing it after?

Comment: Not able to get image to DB with image on my server

Comment: Show us more code. The `view` where you try to fetch the images, the `model` definition and maybe `settings.py`

Comment: Will do, I'm almost there for you but got to dash, will post later if no-one else gets there

Comment: @rockingskier np please guide me when you are free.Thanks

Comment: @Mayank Jain. There you go.

Comment: @rockingskier - This isn't working either..Am able to save it to DB but not able to download images to appropriate path

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28831/discussion-between-rockingskier-and-mayank-jain)

Comment: My mistake solution is working Perfectly...Actually Heroku's servers are read only...and as soon as images are downloaded to server they are deleted..This was the problem

Comment: I know this isn't an acceptable comment, but this helped me tons! Thank you, @rockingskier

Comment: I don't understand this statement: `image = Image()`

Comment: That is creating an instance of a Model so you can save the downloaded image against it. Ie `user = User(); user.avatar.save(...)`

Comment: use res.headers['content-disposition'] for [getting filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804799/how-to-get-pdf-filename-with-python-requests)

Comment: A couple tangent questions if anyone can answer: why is it called "streaming" and why is a temporary file needed?

Comment: Thank you Brother :)

Answer (score 37):

If you want to save downloaded images without saving them to disk first (without using `NamedTemporaryFile` etc) then there's an easy way to do that.

This will be slightly quicker than downloading the file and writing it to disk as it is all done in memory. Note that this example is written for Python 3 - the process is similar in Python 2 but slightly different.

```
from django.core import files
from io import BytesIO
import requests

url = "https://example.com/image.jpg"
resp = requests.get(url)
if resp.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
    #  Error handling here

fp = BytesIO()
fp.write(resp.content)
file_name = url.split("/")[-1]  # There's probably a better way of doing this but this is just a quick example
your_model.image_field.save(file_name, files.File(fp))
```

Where `your_model` is an instance of the model you'd like to save to and `.image_field` is the name of the `ImageField`.

See the documentation for [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

```
# this is my solution
from django.core import files
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

import requests
from .models import MyModel

def download_img():
    r = requests.get("remote_file_url", allow_redirects=True)
    filename = "remote_file_url".split("/")[-1]

    my_model = MyModel(
        file=files.File(ContentFile(r.content), filename)
    )
    my_model.save()

    return
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

As an example of what I think you're asking:

**In forms.py:**

```
imgfile = forms.ImageField(label = 'Choose your image', help_text = 'The image should be cool.')
```

**In models.py:**

```
imgfile =   models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%m/%d')
```

So there will be a POST request from the user (when the user completes the form).  That request will contain basically a dictionary of data.  The dictionary holds the submitted files.  To focus the request on the file from the field (in our case, an ImageField), you would use:

```
request.FILES['imgfield']
```

You would use that when you construct the model object (instantiating your model class):

```
newPic = ImageModel(imgfile = request.FILES['imgfile'])
```

To save that the simple way, you'd just use the save() method bestowed upon your object (because Django is that awesome):

```
if form.is_valid():
    newPic = Pic(imgfile = request.FILES['imgfile'])
    newPic.save()
```

Your image will be stored, by default, to the directory you indicate for MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py.

**Accessing the image in the template:**

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.imgfile.name }}"></img>
```

The urls can be tricky, but here's a basic example of a simple url pattern to call the stored images:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want to involve forms in middle because I am not asking user to input the image.Can you please tell me bug in code which I pasted in question ?

Comment: You claimed you don't know how to use ImageField, so I guided you on that.  You didn't really specify what you're trying to do exactly, and your code is vague.  If you're trying to save the image in a special way, you'll have to modify save().

Comment: sorry for vauge code...what  i want is this..i am asking user to enter one url...i will extract all images of this url and then  i have to save these extracted urls along with some other information in db...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @boltsfrombluesky's answer above you can do this in Python 3 without any external dependencies like so:

```
from os.path import basename
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import tempfile

from django.core.files.base import File

def handle_upload_url_file(url, obj):
    img_temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    req = urllib.request.Request(
        url, data=None,
        headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
        }
    )
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        img_temp.write(response.read())
    img_temp.flush()
    filename = basename(urlparse(url).path)
    result = obj.image.save(filename, File(img_temp))
    img_temp.close()
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way instead of assigning path to the image...

```
    import urllib2
    from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile
    def handle_upload_url_file(url):
        img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120427 Firefox/15.0a1')]
        img_temp.write(opener.open(url).read())
        img_temp.flush()
        return img_temp
```

use the above function like this..

```
    new_image = images_data()
    #rest of the data in new_image and then do this.
    new_image.image.save(slug_filename,File(handle_upload_url_file(url)))
    #here slug_filename is just filename that you want to save the file with.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are saving image by overriding models' save method to modify the name of file and struggling with random invalid filename(like me) in django. You can follow up below code (Copied from Accepted answer):

```
lf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()


for block in response.iter_content(1024*8):

        if not block:
            break

        lf.write(block)
    lf.name = name.  # Set your custom file name here
    dc = ImageFile(file=files.File(lf))

    dc.file.save()
```

I have configured my storage with django-storages, in order to directly upload media content to s3. For some reasons I wasn't able to replace file name. After some R&D it worked.

**Note: I have used FileField in the model, hence few line of code is not needed**

Answer (score -2):

```
def qrcodesave(request): 
    import urllib2;   
    url ="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=s&chld=H|0"; 
    opener = urllib2.urlopen(url);  
    mimetype = "application/octet-stream"
    response = HttpResponse(opener.read(), mimetype=mimetype)
    response["Content-Disposition"]= "attachment; filename=aktel.png"
    return response
```

Comment: What you've done there is describe how to force the user's browser to download the image. OP wants to save the image to an `ImageField` in his database.