# Saving an Image in Django from a request.get

Tags: python, django, image, python-3.x, request

So, I'm attempting to use request.get to pull an image from the web and save it to a django database. This is some code as follows and the steps that I have attempted:

My Model (just the needed bit, not all of it)

```
class Pistol(models.Model):
    gun_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/inventory', blank=True)
```

My Code (I'm doing this from a shell so it may seem unorganized slightly)

```
import request

r = requests.get('http://media.server.theshootingwarehouse.com/small/2451.jpg')
item = Pistol(gun_id="1", price=400, image="1.jpg")
item.image.save('1.jpg',r.content)
```

And then I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Note I am working in `python3`.

Comment: This could help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/#file-storage

Comment: You might want to check [this answer][1].

Hope this helps! :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174022/download-a-remote-image-and-save-it-to-a-django-model

Comment: you'd probably want to save the image to a temporary file and then attach it the model instance

Comment: `request` != `requests`

Answer (score 2):

For python3 i created a Management command i hope it can help you

```
import requests
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from app.models import MyModel


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'save images to MyModel table'


   def handle(self, *args, **options):
     for model in MyModel.objects.all():
        url = 'url_path_to_image'
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = r.content
            filename = url.split('/')[-1]
            model.image.save(filename, ContentFile(data))
            model.save()
            print(model.pk)
    self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Successfully saved MyModel images'))
```